# Performance issues in processing loop

Tags: c#, performance, nested-loops

While iterating through a dataset of roughly 3000 `float` values and running an inner loop, this code runs through the first 10% in seconds but takes 20 minutes to complete the last 90%. The number of `new` objects created has been reduced as much as practical.

Calling `GC.Collect();` then `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` at fixed intervals in the outer loop resulted in no change.

**How can fast performance be maintained through the entire loop?** An actual class is used instead of Object.

Public method:

```
    public static float [] Compute
            ( ref float [] sourceData , ref Object [] referenceData,
              ref float [] progress )
    {

        int count = 0;
        float [] result = new float [sourceData.length];
        float inverseLength = 1f / ((float) sourceData.length);

        for ( int i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++ )
        {

            progress [0] = ( (float) i ) * inverseLength ;
            result[i] = computeDatum (ref sourceData [i], ref referenceData);

            if (count++ == 100)
            {
                count = 0;
                GC.Collect ( );
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers ( );
            }
        }

        return result; 
    }
```

Inner loop in private method:

```
    private static float computeDatum
             ( ref float sourceDatum , ref Object [] referenceData)
    {

        Object workingObject = new Object();
        float result = 0f;

        foreach ( Object o in referenceData )
        {
            workingObject = new Object(o);
            //...perform transformation operations on workingObject...
            //...store results of computation with result...
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Why have you used `ref` for all your parameters? There's no obvious need for it...

Comment: You've got the `c#` tag on the question, no need to repeat it in the title and at the top of your question :).

Comment: Calling GC.Collect() within a loop? Hmm... Not the best thing to do. You can't complain about performance then

Comment: I thought the `ref` would avoid allocating memory for `new` objects but if not I'll delete. Thanks!

Comment: @bbougot no change with or without the GC. I'll take it out (in the real code, will leave in here)

Comment: I think that without knowing what computeDatum is doing and without using the real object instead of an Object, it is near impossible to know why it is slow.

Comment: I would try to improve the algorithm if it's possible. In terms of time complexity it's quadratic (O^2). Try to make it logarithmic or so

Comment: Looking again, the one thing that stands out to me is storing the results of the computation. @RichardKlassen how are you saving the results?

Comment: @Jeff Silver The object is a custom Triangle class which has coordinates for each point and methods to return a normal vector and compute intersection with ray. The algorithm is heavy with trig functions, primarily sin cos and atan.

Comment: @RichardKlassen are those results being written to a database or saved in any way (that's what I assumed "store results of computation") meant?

Comment: Using a profiler would help more than guessing. The non free editions of Visual Studio comes with a quite good one.

Comment: @bbougot & Jeff: I've minimized the number of computations in the algorithm. The number of cycles/operations in computeDatum loop is constant from start to finish in the outer loop which is why I thought this is a memory issue. I'm not an expert in that which is why I reached out for help.

Comment: Jeff, results are being stored in a simple array then written to a binary file after the loops finish. I'm not calling any external SDKs nor any non-array data structures.

Comment: @Alois Kraus thanks for the suggestion. If there isn't an obvious rookie mistake here then I'll try the profiler. Appreciated

Comment: Well, making your snippet compilable and running it with all arrays allocated with 3000 elements executes in milliseconds in Debug inside VS(i.e. with no any optimizations). Apparently the bottleneck is inside the code not shown.